# Property 'match' does not exist on type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'

Tags: typescript, react-router

I'm at a loss. I'm still new to typescript and I did try several proposed solutions that I found on other threads, such as importing `RouteProps` or `RouteComponentProps` and applying them to `React.FC<RouteProps>`, but `match`, `params`, and `id` still do not exist.

I tried to create some interfaces, but I'm not entirely sure how to type objects {}. Because `match` and `params` are objects, while `id` is string..

Below is the code I'm working with. Any input would be much appreciated.

```
const Cocktail: React.FC = (props) => {
  const { cocktail } = useSelector((state: StoreState) => state.cocktails);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { match: { params: { id }}} = props;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchCocktail(id));
  }, []);
  return (
    html elements...
  );
};
```

Comment: I can look at this more closely in a bit.  One option is to get the values from the router hooks rather than from props.  But basically the RouteProps, hooks, etc are all generic. They don’t know that the params includes a string property id unless you tell it what your params are by specifying the generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add the react-router prop `RouteComponentProps` to your component props, it knows that your props include a property `match` which has a property `params` which is an `object`.  What it does not know (yet) is what properties exist in `params`.

If you think about it, the param names are determined by what you place in your route match strings, so the param names are something that's specific to your implementation of the router.

The type `RouteComponentProps<Params>` takes a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type argument `Params` which allows you to specify what the match params are.  You can do this either inline or by defining a interface for your props:

```
const Cocktail: React.FC<RouteComponentProps<{id: string}>> = (props) => {
```

or

```
interface MyParams {
    id: string;
}

const Cocktail: React.FC<RouteComponentProps<MyParams>> = (props) => {
```

Now when you try to access properties on `props.match.params` typescript and your IDE will know that the properties are `id` and nothing else.

Comment: out of curiosity I was able to handle this by creating the following interface. `interface Props { match: {params: { id: string; }; }; }`. I wish I can do multiple lines in comments, I'm sorry; but if this also works, is `RouteComponentProps` necessary?

Comment: That’s fine too.  Essentially you are saying that you need just that one prop and not the entire RouteComponentProps object.

Answer (score 0):

You may also add match to your props type

```
import { match } from 'react-router-dom';
interface DetailsProps {
  required: string;
  match?: match<DetailParams>;
}
```

`DetailParams` is an object representing url parameters, ex:

```
interface DetailParams {
  id: string;
}
```

more details [here](https://sodocumentation.net/react-router/topic/9815/react-router-4-with-typescript)